# Spring + Quartz: programmatic schedule of one-time, misfire proof jobs

Tags: java, spring, triggers, quartz

I am working on an enterprise application that uses Quartz 2.2.1. 
Trigger beans are configured in their XML, which included the relative cron expression.

Now, I have the need of programmatically creating triggers with custom fire times; these triggers also have to handle misfiring (I have to be sure that they get executed, even if the server is down at fire time). Is there a way to make quartz do the 'dirty' work without handling trigger persistency manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than I thought, solution lies within the `SimpleTrigger` class.

// Update trigger infos

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger)builder
                        .startAt( whenever you want it to start )
                        .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInMinutes( or any interval ).repeatForever() )
                        .endAt( whenever you want it to end)
                        .build()
```

This creates a quartz trigger living between start and end, and executing following the specified interval.

Misfire strategy can be specified as well.